# Sqlalchemy best practice for creating and naming sql tables based on new table creations

Tags: database, python-3.x, sqlite, sqlalchemy

As the title suggests I need help understanding how to link new tables to an existing sqlalchemy class, if that's even the proper understanding.

```
dbstring = 'sqlite:///db.db'
engine = create_engine(dbstring)
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()

Base = declarative_base()
metadata = MetaData

class SomeTable(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'somename'
    table_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    value_a = Column(Float())
    value_b = Column(String())
    value_c = Column(Float())
```

I'd like to use the class as a way to control values inserted into future tables. Is there a way to use sqlalchemy to issue a create table command in a format similar to:

```
table_named_foo = SomeTable(value_a = 12.3, value_b = 'bar', value_c = 45.6)
session.commit(table_named_foo)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC I believe that the question is asking why you are able to insert on object of type string into a column that was defined as `Float` or vice-versa. This is because SQLLite uses dymanic typing and will let you put any type into a column regardless of how it was defined.

See here for more info: https://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q3

Try this is in PostgreSQL and you will likely get the behavior you are expecting